# Allow only GET, POST and HEAD HTTP methods

Tags: java, http-method

I have a java application which gone through security audit. The auditor asked me to allow only GET, POST and HEAD HTTP methods.
How to do that?

Comment: Are you using spring boot ?

Comment: No, Its working on struts 1.x framework.